# Renaming Folders using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

so this has been puzzling me 
I need to help to make this `('Dir /D /S A:D')` 
work with `ren "New Folder" New Files"`

I have tried different ways, but I just can't get the folders renamed 
First attempt 
@ECHO OFF

```
FOR /D %%d IN ('Dir /D /S A:D') DO (
       REN "New Folder" "New Files"
)
```

Second attempt

```
@echo off

FOR /D %%D IN ('Dir /D /S A:D') DO RENAME "%%D\New Folder" New Files
```

Third attempt

```
@echo off

FOR /D %%D IN ('Dir /D /S A:D') DO CALL :RENAME %%D

:RENAME
SET CRITERIA=\New Folder
FOR /D %%R IN (%1%CRITERIA%) DO RENAME %%R "New Files"
```

what I want to do is rename folders. I have many Folders and Subfolders 
and every main Directory folder has different names so the script needs to read past every folder and find `New Folder` and rename it to `New Files`

```
layout
Main Folder
---- Folder 1
------| New Folder
---- Folder 2
------| Folder 22
----------| New Folder
```

New folder is found in many different locations so the script needs to be able to read main folders, sub folders, and so on

any help with this will great

Updated Question

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b a:d "New Folder"') do (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "New Files"
)
```

Before

```
Main Folder...
Rename folder.bat
....| New Folder
......| New Folder
........| New Folder
```

Bad RESULTS

```
Main Folder...
Rename folder.bat
....| New Folder
......| New Files
........| New Folder
```

What it should do

```
Main Folder...
Rename folder.bat
....| New Folder
......| New Files
........| New Files
```

Need help with this

I even tried this

```
@echo off

for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b /a:d "New Folder"') do ren "%%f" "New Files"
```

Comment: Type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the usage information very carefully; you will notice, that you are confusing `for /D` and `for /F`…

Comment: OK, so I re did my script using `/f and "tokens"`, but now I have a new problem, not sure how to fix it, I have updated my question @aschipfl

Comment: in Most cases the third New Folder won't exist, but once in a while it will, how can I loop my script to continue working until the last New folder is found, what I do now is I run it 3 times just to make sure it's done

Comment: It appears my script has an error, when I run it, it renames the folders but only if I have another folder next to New Folder, like this `New Folder, New Folder (1)` If I remove the the New folder (1) the script renames the next item in the directory I'm sure the problem is with the * in Tokens

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow, neither can I test it right now; anyway, in your updated code, you do not need delayed expansion and you do not need to set a variable in the loop; but you should use `dir /S /B /A:D` to always *exclude files*, even though they were called `New Folder`…

Comment: @aschipfl - Thank you for the response the `a:d` fixed the renaming of other folders and files, I will update my question once more, and no hurry on the testing, when you get a chance for variable, should it be like this `for /f in ('dir`

Comment: @aschipfl - once again thank you - I have updated the quote for the updated script - and I also added Before and after results - I tried to remove the Variable but it didn't work without it

Comment: Argh, stupid me! I should have noticed, that `for /F "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "New Folder"') do ren "%%f" "New Files"` cannot work, because this first builds the directory tree to iterate, from top to bottom, then renames one item after another, failing for the first child of an already renamed parent; it will work when the order is reversed, like this: `for /F "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "New Folder" ^| sort /R') do ren "%%f" "New Files"`

Comment: great Thank you - I will test and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you seem to confuse [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) with [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), and it is the latter you need to use here:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "New Folder"') do (
    …
)
```

This iterates through the whole directory tree rooted at the current working directory (which is not necessarily the container of the batch script!). The `tokens=*` option of `for /F` ensures that white-spaces in the paths are maintained (removing leading ones, but such are anyway not possible for paths). The switch `/A:D-H-S` of [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) ensures that files, as well as hidden and system directories, are excluded.

But there is one more problem: `dir /S` returns the items in a per-branch basis from top to the bottom of the hierarchy, and `for /F`, together with `dir`, lets the whole directory tree be built before loop iteration begins. So when now renaming a certain directory in the loop body, any children of it get new paths, although the old ones are buffered, letting the renaming fail. For instance, when directory `D:\Path\To\Root\New Folder` becomes renamed to `D:\Path\To\Root\New Files`, a sub-directory `D:\Path\To\Root\New Folder\New Folder` does no longer exist, since its path is now `D:\Path\To\Root\New Files\New Folder`, hence it cannot be found.

To overcome this issue, simply reverse the whole directory tree to be iterated by [`sort`](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html):

```cmd
cd /D "D:\Path\To\Root" & rem // (use `%~dp0.` to specify a path relative to the container of this script)
for /F "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /S /B /A:D-H-S "New Folder" ^| sort /R') do (
    ren "%%f" "New Files"
)
```

That way, the sub-directory `D:\Path\To\Root\New Folder\New Folder` is renamed first, before its parent `D:\Path\To\Root\New Folder` becomes processed.

Comment: Yes, I had figured that the third New folder was not getting renamed do to the folders getting renamed  and eliminating the path - I wasn't sure how to make it go reverse - I learned about sort, did not know we could add it to this, I use sort for sorting context - well I was getting close never used `H-S` before - This works perfectly Thank you - I might have 1 more question about `cd /D` let me test that

Comment: [`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) just changes the current directory; `/D` is necessary to change the drive as well…

Comment: OK - so like this `cd /D "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Main Folder` and everything after rem is just notes right @aschipfl

Comment: You forgot the closing `"`, but yes, `rem` is just a remark…

Comment: I've used `cd /d "%~dp0"` for connecting 2 scripts, but never for a path - not sure how to set that up, I am familiar with this `%~dp0main folder` to eliminate a path, like this `cd /d "%~dp0." "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Main Folder`, or like this `cd /d "%~dp0.Main Folder"` - Oh I just forgot to copy `"` it the to comment

Comment: OK - I got it figured out using the `cd /d` and I did notices that in the script you offered is missing `%` here `for /F "tokens=*" %f ` and the `.` got me confused here use `%~dp0.`